# How to deserealize a List of custom object?

Tags: c#, .net, xml-serialization

This is my Model class:

```
 public class ModelClass
 {
    public ModelClass()
    {
    }

    public ModelClass(string operationName)
    {
        OperationName = operationName;
    }
    public string OperationName { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
 }
```

I have to serialize a list of this model class to a database table:
The table schema is:

```
ModelObjectContent (the serialized string)
IDModel
```

The method wich I use to serialize:

```
  public static string SerializeObject(this List<ModelClass> toSerialize)
    {
        var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(toSerialize.GetType());
        var textWriter = new StringWriter();

        xmlSerializer.Serialize(textWriter, toSerialize);
        return textWriter.ToString();
    }
```

When I save it to the database the string generated is like this:

```
 <ArrayOfChartModel>
     <ModelClass>
         <OperationName>Chart1</OperationName>
         <Count >1</Count>
      </ModelClass>
      <ModelClass>
         <OperationName>Chart2</OperationName>
         <Count >2</Count>
    </ModelClass>
    //etc
 </ArrayOfChartModel>
```

The framework automattically creates a tag named ArrayOfChartModel and thats ok,
but my question is:
How to deserealize this xml to a list of ModelClass again?

Comment: Look at this that I answered before. It might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23369197/how-to-create-c-sharp-objects-using-xml/23372505#23372505

Comment: Oh and this is a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/608110/is-it-possible-to-deserialize-xml-into-listt

Comment: @OhaxNuv this question asks how to desearilize a list of an object, and the correct answer is about to serialize. I dont get it.

Comment: The second comment I added is the exact answer to what you said `How to deserealize this xml to a list of ModelClass again?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
    public static List<ModelClass> Deserialize(string xml)
    {
        var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ModelClass));
        using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(xml))
        {
            return(List<ModelClass>)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, i tried this already, but im getting this exception for all that ive tried: *{"<ArrayOfChartModel xmlns=''> not expected."}*

Comment: Your serialized document does not seem to match normal form of the xml serializer. It is missing some special Tags:<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ArrayOfChartModel xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">